# what would be the configuration for mapStruct to stop mapping a DTO's super class's fields?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, mapstruct

I am having a DTOs class which is extending `spring-hateoas`'s `ResourceSupport` class. The `UserMinimalDto` is a DTO for `User` entity.

So, for generating the mapper classes, I am using [mapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/).

```
@Data //from lambok
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class UserMinimalDto extends ResourceSupport {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    String uniqueId;
    String profilePicUrl;

}
```

I am using `ResourceSupport` to add hateoas links to the response from the controller.

The Mapper interface

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMinimalMapper {

    UserMinimalMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMinimalMapper.class) ;

    UserMinimalDto entityToDto(User user);

    User dtoToEntity(UserMinimalDto userMinimalDto);
}
```

But when I run `mvn clean install` on the project, I am facing compilation error

> Can't map property "org.springframework.hateoas.Link id" to
>   "java.lang.Integer id". Consider to declare/implement a mapping
>   method: "java.lang.Integer map(org.springframework.hateoas.Link
>   value)".

This is because the `mapStruct` is trying the map the fields of `ResourceSupport`. 
Its works if:

1. I remove extends ResourceSupport from UserMinimalDto
2. I remove dtoToEntity(UserMinimalDto userMinimalDto); from mapper
   interface

What would be the configuration to tell `mapStruct` to not map the super class fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to ignore fields on a case by case bases you can use `Mapping#ignore`.

In your case it will look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMinimalMapper {

    UserMinimalMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMinimalMapper.class) ;

    UserMinimalDto entityToDto(User user);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "links", ignore = true)
    User dtoToEntity(UserMinimalDto userMinimalDto);
}
```

In case you have a common interface / class for your entities you can use `@MapperConfig` and define those exclusions.

It can look something like:

```
@MapperConfig(mappingInheritanceStrategy = MappingInheritanceStrategy.AUTO_INHERIT_FROM_CONFIG)
public interface CommonMappingConfig {

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "links", ignore = true)
    BaseEntity map(ResourceSupport resourceSupport);

}

@Mapper(config = CommonMappingConfig.class)
public interface UserMinimalMapper {

    UserMinimalMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMinimalMapper.class) ;

    UserMinimalDto entityToDto(User user);

    User dtoToEntity(UserMinimalDto userMinimalDto);
}
```

Comment: what would be the `BaseEntity` here? An interface/class implemented by all of my entity classes? or the DTO classes?

Comment: It would be an interface / class implemented / extended by all your entity classes. The DTO classes extend `ResourceSupport`

Comment: Is there a way to inherit multiple `config`s?  (because this approach is not scalable)
Alternative approach could be applying `@AfterMapping` but it makes the reading of generated mapper harder since we need to jump back and forth to see the mappings.

Comment: There is a feature request for that, currently there is no such thing out of the box

Answer (score 1):

It's because the model class has other set of fields than `DTO`, and your mapper maps both ways. But that is pretty natural, dto doesn't have an id.

The workaround would be to exclude those fields from mapping for example by annotating `id` and other fields in model class, that aren't in dto with: `Mapping("this")`.

Comment: It's not completely related to the the model class i.e `User` here. If I remove `extends ResourceSupport` from `UserMinimalDto`, the mapper maps both the way perfectly. It's the `ResourceSupport` causing the issue.

Comment: I have other DTOs and mappers which don't require `ResourceSupport` and they map the field both ways perfectly.